# Minecraft item stat commands isn't working (minecraft pc, 1.9.4 [no mods])

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

so I was trying to make a room where I can quickly generate items/ armoury, through command block, but it seems that the armour stats show, but it does not function the same. here is a simple command for the armour I use: (all the uuid are changed, and are different, by the most uuid has been decreased by 1 and the least uuid has been added by 1 per item):

chest piece:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_chestplate 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:298103,UUIDMost:329215},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:99999,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:461333,UUIDMost:621632},{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"generic.armor",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:121228,UUIDMost:767793},{AttributeName:"generic.luck",Name:"generic.luck",Amount:2500,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:854645,UUIDMost:31500},{AttributeName:"generic.armorToughness",Name:"generic.armorToughness",Amount:99999,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:686589,UUIDMost:713961}],Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Legendary ARES chest armor",Lore:[armor said to withstand the most fearful attacks!]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:32767},{id:1,lvl:32767},{id:3,lvl:32767},{id:4,lvl:32767},{id:7,lvl:32767}]}
```

helmet:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_helmet 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:298104,UUIDMost:329214},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:99999,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:461334,UUIDMost:621631},{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"generic.armor",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:121229,UUIDMost:767792},{AttributeName:"generic.luck",Name:"generic.luck",Amount:2500,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:854646,UUIDMost:31499},{AttributeName:"generic.armorToughness",Name:"generic.armorToughness",Amount:99999,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:686590,UUIDMost:713960}],Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Legendary ARES helmet Armor",Lore:[armor said to withstand the most fearful attacks!]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:32767},{id:1,lvl:32767},{id:3,lvl:32767},{id:4,lvl:32767},{id:5,lvl:5},{id:6,lvl:32767},{id:7,lvl:32767}]}
```

leggings:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_leggings 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:298105,UUIDMost:329213},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:99999,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:461335,UUIDMost:621630},{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"generic.armor",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:121230,UUIDMost:767791},{AttributeName:"generic.luck",Name:"generic.luck",Amount:2500,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:854647,UUIDMost:31498},{AttributeName:"generic.armorToughness",Name:"generic.armorToughness",Amount:99999,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:686591,UUIDMost:713959}],Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Legendary ARES leggings Armor",Lore:[armor said to withstand the most fearful attacks!]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:32767},{id:1,lvl:32767},{id:3,lvl:32767},{id:4,lvl:32767},{id:7,lvl:32767}]}
```

boots:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_boots 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:298106,UUIDMost:329212},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:99999,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:461330,UUIDMost:621629},{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"generic.armor",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:121231,UUIDMost:767790},{AttributeName:"generic.luck",Name:"generic.luck",Amount:2500,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:854648,UUIDMost:31497},{AttributeName:"generic.armorToughness",Name:"generic.armorToughness",Amount:99999,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:686592,UUIDMost:713958}],Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Legendary ARES boots Armor",Lore:[armor said to withstand the most fearful attacks!]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:32767},{id:1,lvl:32767},{id:2,lvl:32767},{id:3,lvl:32767},{id:4,lvl:32767},{id:7,lvl:32767},{id:8,lvl:32767},{id:9,lvl:32767}]}
```

the problem is when I used my custom arrows on myself, with 'like' no power (inside, as it can cause levitate which causes falling damage), I can withstand the arrows with no armour, but with my command armour I die straight away on hit...

the custom arrow and bow (pvp bow) are:

bow:

```
/give @p minecraft:bow 1 0 {Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"eliete bow",Lore:[bow made for tactical combat, and strategic use! ]},ench:[{id:49,lvl:10},{id:51,lvl:9999}]}
```

arrows:

```
/give @p[team=] minecraft:tipped_arrow 64 0 {display:{Lore:[arrows of death]},CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:2,Amplifier:100,Duration:1000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:9,Amplifier:100,Duration:400,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:15,Amplifier:100,Duration:300,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:17,Amplifier:3,Duration:800,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:19,Amplifier:1,Duration:1200,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:24,Amplifier:100,Duration:6000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:25,Amplifier:10,Duration:600,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

Comment: Wrong place to ask, ask in the Minecraft forums or Minecraft subreddit for help with commands

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Attribute), the max stat for `armorToughness` is 20. I would assume they set it to that as setting it any higher resulted in unexpected things such as instant death (probably a math issue in armor/damage calculations). Try setting it to 20 instead of 9999 and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: hmm... i tried that, and same result, this armour seems useless... i mean whats the point for pvp if u die straight away, well at least i know the special arrows are good...

Comment: @N-ninja: Did you try changing all the stats to 20? It could always be one of the others

Comment: Well i did use the website ( wiki, listed above) to change all the other stats to the max (well not all to the max, but in between) that it (wiki) suggested, so i really dont know what went wrong, i will post the edited code later on, as im not exactly on my computer at the moment...